# How do I load files into Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file

I was wondering how to load a file from my System Libraries, but I'm not sure how. I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
require 'gosu'
require "Picture.jpg"
```

and then having the rest of my code, but every time I try that, I get the error:

```
No such file to load
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or there just isn't a way to load a file from my system library into Ruby?

Comment: Require is only for ruby code - requiring a jpg won't ever work

Comment: Is "Picture.jpg" a file written in Ruby?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by loading "Picture.jpg"? `require` will read a system file or a gem, which consist of Ruby code. Ruby would have no idea what to do with a binary "jpg" file and would raise an error immediately. It's possible to tell Ruby to read a binary file into a variable for processing in some way, but unless we know what you intend to do with it we won't be able to help you further.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to take close looks at `require`, `load`, `extend` and `include`.

It will help you to use in your application.

http://ionrails.com/2009/09/19/ruby_require-vs-load-vs-include-vs-extend/

Comment: thetinman, i didn't acutally mean to load a jpg file. I was just giving an example of a random name of a file for the coding. I have a lot of files in my system, and I just didn't feel like digging through all my files. frederick and saws, u r right but again, not a real file i have.